# How to pass REST data in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm trying to understand node by making a single page app that just generates paragraphs and is told how many to generate.

My understanding of using REST looks like this

```
const ipsum_gen = require("./generator.js");

let routes = app => {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Site is working!");
  });

  app.get("/ipsum", (req, res) => {
    let data = ipsum_gen.getAllParagraphs(1);
    res.status(200).send(data);
  });

  app.get("/ipsum/:num", (req, res) => {
    let data = [];
    let num = req.params.num;
    if (isFinite(num) && num > 0) {
      data = ipsum_gen.getAllParagraphs(num);
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
    else {
      res.status(400).send({ message: "That is not a number." });
    }
  });
};
```

Instead of sending the data directly to the page to be rendered as text on a white background, how do I send it to an html template which can present it in a nicer way?

Answer (score 0):

In your node rest js return data using response.json, For example :

```
app.get('/api/getAllData', (req, res) => {
    EXAMPLEDATA.getObjects((err, pass) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(pass);
    });
});
```

And as above you have created a rest api end point you need to consume the api using a ajax call and read the json and put it in your HTML page using javascript.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
const ipsum_gen = require("./generator.js");

let routes = app => {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(`This should be an HTML page, 
       possibly containing a form
       and a JS script to call one of the api routes
       and update the page with the data recieved`);
  });

  app.get("/ipsum", (req, res) => {
    let data = ipsum_gen.getAllParagraphs(1);
    res.status(200).send(data);
  });

  app.get("/ipsum/:num", (req, res) => {
    let data = [];
    let num = req.params.num;
    if (isFinite(num) && num > 0) {
      data = ipsum_gen.getAllParagraphs(num);
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
    else {
      res.status(400).send({ message: "That is not a number." });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: If I have a JS script in the html to call the api routes, doesn't that reload the entire page to update it? I don't want to reload the page, that's why I am trying this REST method.

Comment: No, exactly the opposite. Letting the Javascript control the data is exactly what allows you to change the contents without reloading the entire page. A good place to start would be the jQuery library, specifically the ajax and get functions.